# Xamarin Forms: Is it possible to use CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout in Material?

Tags: android, xamarin, material-design, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement the following: http://blog.grafixartist.com/quick-return-pattern-with-android-design-support-library/

When I create a new Forms project, I get the following `Toolbar.axml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And `MainActivity.cs`

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ListViewT.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ListViewT", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at `FormsAppCompatActivity`, there doesn't seem to be anything for those layouts:

```
public class FormsAppCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity, IDeviceInfoProvider, IStartActivityForResult
    {
        protected FormsAppCompatActivity();

        public static int TabLayoutResource { get; set; }
        public static int ToolbarResource { get; set; }

        public static event BackButtonPressedEventHandler BackPressed;
        public event EventHandler ConfigurationChanged;

        public override void OnBackPressed();
        public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig);
        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item);
        public void SetStatusBarColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color color);
        protected void LoadApplication(Application application);
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data);
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
        protected override void OnDestroy();
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent);
        protected override void OnPause();
        protected override void OnRestart();
        protected override void OnResume();
        protected override void OnStart();
        protected override void OnStop();

        public delegate bool BackButtonPressedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    }
```

Is it possible to leverage `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: It's possible in native Android, so I don't understand your question. Where is the CoordinatorLayout in your question?

Comment: You could refer here.  https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportdesign

Comment: I don't mean native Android. I mean Xamarin Forms. If you look at MainActivity, it derives from FormsAppCompatActivity. It has TabLayoutResource and ToolbarResource but no CoordinatorLayoutResource or AppBarLayoutResource.

Comment: I just searched Xamarin CoordinatorLayout and I hit that link first, so I'm sure there are some resources out there as a solution

Comment: CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout are mentioned in the link I gave.

Comment: They are also mentioned in the link I gave, except in the context of Xamarin.

Comment: I think they are only available for Xamarin.Android. Maybe if/when they are available for Forms, somebody could post an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that was the same thing. Does this code help?  https://github.com/nativecode-dev/oss-xamarin/blob/master/src/NativeCode.Mobile.AppCompat/FormsAppCompat/AppCompatFormsApplicationActivity.cs